# How to determine if two lines in 3D intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I've seen literally dozens of "line segment" intersect solutions from my trip around the Internet, but that's not ideal for my situation.

> Given a single point on each line and a vector representing the direction of said line, is it possible to tell whether the lines intersect?

I'm going to be implementing an algorithm to do this in C++ if it's possible without defining endpoints which (due to integral / floating point precision) will undoubtedly cause accuracy errors when dealing with lines that push the bounds of precision.

Comment: In 2D, unless the vectors are parallel, the two lines will always intersect. Are you asking how to check whether two vectors are parallel?

Comment: I'm speaking in terms of 3D, sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: If you are referring to a directed "half-line", the word *ray* might better describe what you ask about (finding an intersection of two rays in 3D).  "Without defining arbitrary endpoints" is not specific enough to follow your meaning.

Comment: Is there a difference between a ray and, as stated in the question above, "a point on the line and the vector of said line" that I'm not aware of?  Perhaps my terminology is a bit off because I haven't taken a linear algebra course in over 10 years.

Comment: @Luke - yes, a ray contains points only on half of the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two non-parallel lines $p_1+\mathbb R v_1$ and $p_2+\mathbb R v_2$ intersect if and only if $(v_1\times v_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)=0$.

(But if you're implementing this in floating-point arithmetic, you're going to need to build in some safety margins anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  Glad to see someone bright enough to understand the question!  If I had enough rep, I'd +1 this answer as well.  Floating point arithmetic is going to be subject to template specialization with an epsilon value, so we're all good.

Comment: If the (v1×v2) multiplication cross or dot product???

Comment: @BenWebb Cross product. (I don't think anyone uses $\times$ to denote the dot product!)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 lines in the parametric notation $(a_1 +tv_1,a_2 + tv_2, a_3 + tv_3)$ and $(b_1 +sw_1,b_2 + sw_2, b_3 + sw_3)$, just compare component by component and see if you can find $s$ and $t$ sotisfying all the 3 equations. Otherwise transoform them in 2 cartesian equations and substitute.